# Why a java same String has different hashcode

Tags: java, string, classloader

I have a class:

```
package com.test;
public class TestA {
    public static final String TEST = "饕餮ABCDEFG";

    public TestA() {
        System.out.println(TEST.hashCode());
    }
}
```

The same class(with no package, put it in E:, javac Test.java, get Test.class):

```
public class TestA {
    public static final String TEST = "饕餮ABCDEFG";

    public TestA() {
        System.out.println(TEST.hashCode());
    }
}
```

The Test class:

```
package com.test;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;


public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URLClassLoader loaderA = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file:E:/")});

        Class clazzA = loaderA.loadClass("TestA");
        clazzA.newInstance();

        TestA testA = new TestA();
    }
}
```

output:

250218913

1111280555

question:
why this happened?
i think the string "饕餮ABCDEFG" has the same address because constant pool. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Pvt.png)

Comment: The constant pool shouldn't be involved at all since the hash code of a string is calculated from the underlying char array (so that 2 different instances still have the same hash code). What do you get when printing the char array itself in both cases (via `TEST.toCharArray()`)?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_161"

Comment: @Thomas the key is 2 different string instances have same String literal and they have different hashCode,

Comment: The _can't_ have the same value and a different hash code. As per the JavaDoc (which the [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) supports): `The hash code for a String object is computed as  s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1] using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation.` - Thus again: what output do you get when printing the character array itself? That there might be non-printable characters in the literal - which you don't see.

Comment: Output the content of the string as well in your code. There is a chance that you created more then two classes with name TestA and class loader finds it

Comment: look at the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Pvt.png, have the same value and a different hash code, you can try it by yourself.

Comment: @Maxim Can you explain a little more detail?

Comment: File encoding when you copied the file? For simple test I copied the file and the string changed to "ΘÑòΘñ«ABCDEFG"

Comment: What Maxim means is the following (I add my requirement as well): Please use this and post the output for both classes here: `System.out.println("hashcode of " + TEST + " is " + TEST.hashCode() + "(text in utf-8 bytes: " + Arrays.toString( TEST.getBytes("UTF-8") ) + ")");`

Comment: I made a silly mistake!  my os is windows10，the default encoding is gbk, and TestA is UTF-8 encoding, so we can't just use javac TestA.class，the right operation is javac -encoding utf-8 TestA.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program output gave the same hashcode for me.

- 1111280555
- 1111280555

The reason(s) why you are getting different hashcode

1. There are some special character which you cannot see. You can
   identify by copying the text in hexed.it
2. One file is stored as UTF8 and another as CP1652 or other encoding.

Comment: you are right, use  javac -encoding utf-8 TestA.java ,and output is same